# How can I change iphone simulator hardware configuration?

Tags: xcode4, cocos2d-iphone, iphone-4

I want to change simulator to show retina display effect.
I try to find where I can change the hardware configuration.
But no result, I get.
Do you know How do you change simulator to show retina display effect?
And After change it, How can I compile project and see that effect?
Please help me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run the project, the hardware options are in the simulator itself, which is a separate application.  They are under the hardware menu.

For the Retina display: Hardware->Device->iPhone (Retina)

[image]

Comment: I use XCode 4.
And I can't find Hardware->Device->iPhone(Retina)
Could you send me a screensnap file?

Comment: Note that have to actually run the application on the Simulator first.  Make sure iPhone 4.3 Simulator is selected in XCode, and then press that run button in the upper-left corner.

Answer (score 1):

The simulator has a device menu where you can choose between the iPad, the original iPhone or the Retina iPhone.

Comment: But I can only see device menu : iPad && iPhone, not Retina iPhone.